# NVD3.js: Is it possible to let user download any graph as JPEG or PNG Image?

Tags: svg, graph, nvd3.js

I want user to let download the charts/graphs as PNG image or JPEG image. Is it possible in NVD3.js to allow user to download in this format?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think nvd3 has the function built in and i have very similar requirement and "[example of how to export a png directly from an svg](http://bl.ocks.org/deanmalmgren/22d76b9c1f487ad1dde6)" solved my problem (internally it adopted [svg-crowbar](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) code). basically, you need to draw the svg to a canvas then export the image to png, and "explicitly set css style" for all svg element is the caveat to make the exported image like original.